web page needs to ignore mouse clicks
I created a blazor page to test proficiency.  Imagine a typing program.
But occasionally, the student will bump the mouse or trackpad causing the edit box to lose focus, invalidating the test.
I think I want to add a div to capture and ignore mouse clicks on the main form, that is, anywhere not on the sidebar or top menu.
I tried both of
<div class="ignoremouseclick" position:fixed; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; z-index:-9999; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); @onclick:preventDefault></div>
<div class="ignoremouseclick" position:fixed; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; z-index:-9999; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); @onclick:"ignoremouse"></div>
private void ignoremouse(MouseEventArgs e) {
    // ignore mouse clicks
}

When I open developer tools, I don't see the div and it doesn't stop the edit box from losing focus.

This could be easier to achieve using js. You could test following
Home.razor
@page "/"

<div id="form1" style="height:200px;width:300px;border:1px solid black;">
    Name
    <p />
    <input id="input1" />
    <p />
    Password
    <p />
    <input id="input2" />
</div>
<script>
    function stopIt(e) {
        if (e.target.id == "form1") {
            e.preventDefault();

        }
    }
        document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener("mousedown", stopIt);
</script>

---------------------------------------update---------------------------------
You could try following code to test:
@page "/"

focus: <input />

<div style="height:200px;width:300px;border:1px solid black;" @onmouseenter="disableClick" @onmouseout="enableClick" @onmousedown="meaningless" @onmousedown:preventDefault="shouldPrevent">
    click in this block will not lose focus to input

</div>
@code{
    private bool shouldPrevent;

    private void meaningless()
    {       
    }
    private void disableClick()
    {
        shouldPrevent = true;

    }
    private void enableClick()
    {
        shouldPrevent = false;
    }
}

Just remind that the @onmousedown="meaningless" method must exist.

Blazor is not supposed to have <script> in markup, so this answer does not follow the recommended practices for Blazor.

Thanks for trying, but I'm trying to avoid js in my blazor files if at all possible.

@BWhite I have managed to test a c# way and post in the answer. You could have a try.

If you really don't want ANY clicks at all, then you can try adding this to your main css file:
body {
    pointer-events: none;
}

Or add "pointer-events: none;" wherever you want not to allow clicks.
Your divs look strange.  Normally the things you put would be in a style block:
<div class="ignoremouseclick" style="position:fixed; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; z-index:-9999; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);" @onclick:preventDefault></div>

I believe if you want to use z-index, you need to set your position to a particular setting.  I suppose fixed would work, but if it doesn't, try googling it.  I think I read once upon a time that it only works with position:relative, but that's a while ago, and only a vague memory.
